# jQuery script not referencing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't figure out why but my script is not working properly as it was working fine before. Now, it is not working anymore and I can't figure out why as I don't remember making any changes to the script tag.

```
<body>
<form id="contact">
    <fieldset id="contactInformation">
        <legend>Contact Information</legend>
        <p id="error"></p>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <br>
        <input id="name" type="text">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
        <br>
        <input id="phoneNumber" type="text">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label id="eMail">E-Mail Address:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label id="address">Address:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label id="city">City:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label id="postalCode">Postal Code:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label id="province">Province</label>
        <br>
        <select id="province">
            <option>Choose Your Province</option>
            <option>Alberta</option>
            <option>British Columbia</option>
            <option>Manitoba</option>
            <option>New Brunswick</option>
            <option>Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
            <option>Northwest Territories</option>
            <option>Nova Scotia</option>
            <option>Nunavut</option>
            <option>Ontario</option>
            <option>Prince Edward Island</option>
            <option>Quebec</option>
            <option>Saskatchewan</option>
            <option>Yukon Territory</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="shipping">
            <label id="shippingCheckbox">Is your shipping information the same as your contact information?</label>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="sameInfo">
            <label>Yes it is</label>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <fieldset id="shippinginformation">
            <legend>Shipping Information</legend>
            <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
            <br>
            <input id="phoneNumber" type="text">
            <br>
            <br>
            <label id="address">Address:</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text">
            <br>
            <br>
            <label id="postalCode">Postal Code:</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text">
            <br>
            <br>
        </fieldset>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

//script.js
var errorNotify = 'Sorry, we could not process your request because '
var errorField = [];

function formVal() {
    var isValid = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < errorField.length; i++ ) {
        $(errorField[i]).removeClass('error');
    }
    errorField = [];

    if(!nameCheck()) {
        isValid = false;
    }
    if(!phoneCheck()) {
        isValid = false;
    }
    if (isValid === false) {
        $('#error').html(errorNotify).hide().slideDown('slow');
        for (var i = 0; i < errorField.length; i++) {
            $(errorField[i]).addClass('error');
        }
        errorNotify = 'Sorry, we could not process your request because ';
    }

    function nameCheck(){
        if ($('#name').val() === '') {
            errorNotify += ' you did not enter your name.';
            errorField.push($('#name'));
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    function phoneCheck(){
        var phoneCheck = $('#phoneNumber').val();
        if (phoneCheck === '') {
            errorNotify += ' you did not enter your phone number.';
            errorField.push($('#phoneNumber'));
            return false;
        } else if (phoneCheck.length !== 10) {
            errorNotify += 'please enter a 10 digit phone number';
            errorField.push($('#phoneNumber'));
        }
        else if (isNaN(parseInt(phoneCheck))) {
            errorNotify += 'you have entered a letter, please enter a number';
            errorField.push($('#phoneNumber'));
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return isValid;
}

$(function () {

    $('#contact').submit(function() {
        return formVal();
    });

    $('#sameInfo').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            alert('this is a test');
        } else {
            alert('this is not a test');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you try to move up your      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>    <script src="js/script.js"></script> codes to top?

Comment: What is not working properly? If you mean your form is not submitted, you did not state form's action on line 2

Comment: @Adam Ginther As is, it shouldn't work, to the best of my knowledge, because your code isn't actually wrapped in a script tag? Or were you just posting your code from the external file at the bottom of your code block here?

Comment: @OzkanOzlu Well, Ozkan, most of my forms don't specify an action attribute, because I intend for it to post back to the same page, which is the default action of forms. Not to say, I'm sure of what he intended, but it is very common.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PVVmy/ I have tried your code. it checks if name is entered and phone is entered and phone number consists of 10 digits. Then it does nothing.

Comment: @AdamGinther I would, however, definitely move your script tags to the head section of your html document, though.

Comment: I've got it working thanks to Ozkan. Thanks guys.

Comment: Must kill the urge ... to ... indent ... code.

Comment: @AdamGinther If you can elaborate on exactly what worked, that would be great for future viewers.

Comment: @MilchePatern I believe I've killed your urge :)

Comment: Hi, could jsLint help you ? --> http://www.jslint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not that it should fail totally because of this, but you're missing return values on your else if's in the phoneCheck() function.

Other than that it looks fine imo.